How to pass a named parameter to npm-run-all command?
I have some scripts in package.json as
"scripts": {
    "report:deleteOldReport": "node deleteReports.js",
    "runCypress": "npx cypress run",
    "report:merge": "mochawesome-merge ./cypress/reports/*.json -o ./cypress/report_Merged/totalReport.json",
    "report:generateHtml": "marge ./cypress/report_Merged/totalReport.json  --reportDir ./ --inline",
    "regressionScripts": "npm-run-all -s -c report:deleteOldReport runCypress  report:merge report:generateHtml"
  }

I run it using command npm run regressionScripts and it works well.
Sometimes I need to pass a parameter --spec /path/tosome/files to the runCypress script. Meaning I want the second script to be executed as npx cypress run --spec /path/to/some/files. I can run the script like npm run runCypress -- --spec /path/to/some/files and it works fine.
The question is how to pass the --spec parameter through npm-run-all (last script) command?
